# Is there a mutual folder where I can save and load data using a simulator or my device?

Tags: swift, path, save, load, persistence

I'm currently saving my data in Document Directory, using this code :

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myData").appendingPathExtension("plist")

let pListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        if let encodedTableArray = try? pListEncoder.encode(myData) {
            try? encodedTableArray.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
        }
```

When I print `documentsDirectory`, whether my app is running on a simulator or my device (plugged to my computer), paths are not similar :

`file:///Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E80B48AB-C269-48ED-9AF4-AC55C34C911E/data/Containers/Data/Application/D3C87E08-DC0E-4F53-ABC7-C930DFAC4EF8/Documents/`

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F5BE0EB0-F2C7-4842-B039-01D5F8CCA4A2/Documents/` ,

respectively.

Is there a path that can be accessed by both simulators and devices ?

PS : I'm using this path just because I read that it's supposed to be the most appropriate path when saving my kind of data (something like a list of tables), I'm still learning about persistency so I'm not fully understanding why however.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Not only the paths are different, the files are on different devices. The simulator's file system is on your Mac, and the device's files system is, well, on the device.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but is there a way to make it communicate or a unique place where both simulator and device can write and fetch data ?